# Attribute contains word selector returning empty array

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, selectors-api

I have some HTML resembling this:

```
<input name="arr[something completely random][something else I can't rely on][initial]" />
<!-- ... -->
<input name="arr[dadedadeda][blahblahblah][initial]" />
```

And my JavaScript `document.querySelectorAll('[name~="initial"]')` returns `[]` (empty). Why? Are multidimensional arrays in names dealt with differently? Is there something I'm missing?

I just tried `document.querySelectorAll('[name$="[initial]"]')`, the `ends with` selector (`attr$="endStr"`), and this returns what I need, but I still need to know why the `attribute contains` selector (`attr~="inStr"`) is failing to work

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, the other question may have the same answer as this question, but it is not the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the word contains filter, the word should be separated by spaces, in your case that fails since you have the word enclosed in `[]`

instead you can use contains selector like

```
document.querySelectorAll('[name*="initial"]')
document.querySelectorAll('[name*="[initial]"]')//to be more specific
```

Comment: Thank you for this, didn't realise there was a difference between contains and... **really** contains

Comment: @Isaac: Think of it as the difference between searching a list of words, and searching a string for a substring. ~= is the former, *= is the latter.

Comment: @BoltClock I ended up sticking with the `ends with` selector, just to eliminate the possibility of `[initial]` being one of the first two keys